# Using matlab coordinates in Blender

Tags: animation, transforms

I am new to Blender and I could really use some help. The idea was to record a movement and animate a 3d character in Blender, but the problem is I didn't get a bvh file or any other mocap data file and instead I got two videos (we used only two cameras) of marker movement and two matlab programs to get the coordinates.

So after I clicked on every marker in every frame of those videos I used the other matlab program to make a 3D reconstruction of markers. Now I have 3D position of those markers in every frame, but I don't know how to use them in blender.

Matlab coordinate system is different from the one in Blender and even when I rotate the coordinates for 270 degrees around x to get the same one I still have a problem because the markers are not positioned in the center as the 3d model in blender is. So basically the question is is there a way to use those coordinates so that the 3d model could still look like a mocap?

Do I need to write coordinates for parent and children bones or do I subtract the values from one another? 
Thank you.

Comment: The matrices are hierarchical and will be multiplied from parent to child bones. For an explaination of the matrix types see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/relationship-between-global-vertex-coordinates-and-mesh-objects-matrix-attribut/15245#15245

Comment: @stacker I'm sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean by multiplied? Let's say z coordinate of shoulder is 9, forearm 6 and hand 5 how do I write them? I don't have any rotation angles, just those coordinates for every frame and every joint

Comment: You would need to calculate the roation matrices, this is supported by the API http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/mathutils.html?highlight=rotation_difference See also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12314/in-python-rotate-a-polygon-to-face-something